Gaussian Distribution as minimizer of difference between two differential entropies
Let $N$ be a Gaussian random variables with variance $\sigma^2$, and let $X$ be another random variable independent of  $N$ with variance $P$. I want to show that the Gaussian distribution for the random variable $X$ minimizes
\begin{align}
h(X)-h(X+N),
\end{align}where $h(\cdot)$ is differential entropy. Any ideas?!

Notice that, since $X$ is independent of $N$, $h(X+N|N) = h(X|N) = h(X)$. But then $$ h(X) -h(X+N) = h(X+N|N) - h(X+N) = -I(X+N;N) = -I(X+N;X).$$ So minimising the functional you have is the same as maximising the mutual information $I(X;X+N).$ This is a classical question, and you can find an analysis in Cover and Thomas (or any source on information theory that deals with continuous laws). Look for material on the capacity of the additive Gaussian channel.

Thanks, but why $I(X+N;N)=I(X+N;X)$? @stochasticboy321

Because you can get $(X, X+N)$ from $(N, X+N)$ by a bijection (as an exercise, show that this means that the two mutual informations are equal. This is probably a problem in Cover and Thomas, so you should be able to find a solution in its solution manual if you get stuck.).

Thanks, but I do not think that this is correct! I can provide you a counter example! @stochasticboy321

Welp, yeah, you're right - that'd preserve entropy but not mutual information ($h(X,X+N) = h(N, X+N) = h(X,N)$, but then mutual information is $h(X) + h(X+N) - h(X,N) \neq h(N) + h(X+N) - h(X,N)$).

@stochasticboy321 If there is a bijection , then the entropies are indeed equal. But that's not true for differential entropies.

So let's see - you want to maximise the mutual information $I(N;N+X)$ where $N$ is fixed. This is like a dual of the channel coding problem: given a fixed signal distribution, what is the noise that maximises the mutual information. I think I've already answered that question (in the negative): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710849/minimizing-differential-entropy-of-a-gaussian-random-variable-conditioned-on-sum/4711119#4711119

@leonbloy Well in this case it's a norm 1 linear transformation, so that's fine. But oof, I seem to be having an off day :)

No, the noise is Gaussian, we want to show that the Gaussian input distribution maximizes I(X+N;N)!@stochasticboy321

Yeah, I'm saying it doesn't. Have a look at the answer I linked (set $A= N$ and $B= X$)

Thanks! So, what do you think is the maximum of I(X+N;N)? @stochasticboy321

As I write in that answer, the supremum of this over all laws is $\infty$, and is achieved by many ways, one of which is the discrete law $X \sim \mathrm{Unif}(\pm \sqrt{P})$. This is easily seen if $\sqrt{P}$ is rational, because in this case $X$ can only affect the first few bits of $X+N$, which means that the tail of $N$ is perfectly preserved by $X+N$, ergo you transmit infinite bits of $N$ with only one use. In general, the point is that given $N$, $X+N$ is discrete, which makes $-h(X+N|N) = \infty$ (and you can approach via a sequence of smooth laws if you want to fuss with the details).

Do you have a reference that claims a Gaussian distribution for $X$ achieves the minimum or are you trying to see whether this claim is correct? It seems to me that Gaussian $X$ is actually a maximizer (not minimizer).
It holds
$$\begin{eqnarray}
h(X, X+N) &=& h(X+N|X) + h(X) \\
&=& h(N)+h(X).
\end{eqnarray}$$
It also holds
$$\begin{eqnarray}
h(X, X+N) &=& h(X|X+N) + h(X+N).
\end{eqnarray}$$
From these two equations, it follows that
$$ h(X) - h(X+N) = h(X|X+N) - h(N)$$
Therefore, minimizing the LHS is equivalent to minimizing $h(X|X+N)$.
If $X$ is Gaussian (and, in turn, jointly Gaussian with $N$), then $X$ conditioned on $X+N$ is also Gaussian, which means that this choice of $X$ actually maximizes $h(X|X+N)$.
